# не удаётся найти класс в библиотеке

Tags: php

подключена библиотека morphos, и пытаюсь просклонять города использую всё как в документации

```
    use morphos\Russian\GeographicalNamesInflection;
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/regions.json'), true);
foreach ($data as $datum) {

    print GeographicalNamesInflection::getCase($datum['cityname'], 'родительный');

}
```

выводит ошибку Uncaught Error: Class 'morphos\Russian\GeographicalNamesInflection' not found in E:\OpenServer\domains\test\testscript.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown сама библиотека установлена, так как через консольку проверял, ну вот так не получается

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```